# How to identify locations of branch mispredictions?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I ran my program through `perf stat -d` and the output included the following results:

```
     3,527,202,599      instructions          #    3.70  insn per cycle
       578,724,753      branches              #    2.679 G/sec
         3,816,842      branch-misses         #    0.66% of all branches
     4,764,220,185      slots                 #   22.058 G/sec
     3,441,864,146      topdown-retiring      #     72.2% Retiring
       597,862,925      topdown-bad-spec      #     12.5% Bad Speculation
       467,080,410      topdown-fe-bound      #      9.8% Frontend Bound
       261,565,029      topdown-be-bound      #      5.5% Backend Bound
       811,364,274      L1-dcache-loads       #    3.756 G/sec
           396,558      L1-dcache-load-misses #    0.05% of all L1-dcache accesses
```

From these, it looks like branch mispredictions are the primary performance bottleneck, with `topdown-bad-spec` being 12.5% and `branch-misses` being 0.66%.

It's great that I know this, but I need to know the *locations* of the mispredictions to try to improve these stats. I did not find this information when I ran `perf record` and `perf report`. Recording by `-e branch-misses` doesn't produce very meaningful results for what I'm looking for.

How do I find these branch misprediction locations?

Comment: `perf record -e branch-misses` / `perf report` would be a simple way to start.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ha I just added a note about this. Results still highlight locations of most time spent, nothing about actual branch mispredictions.

Comment: What CPU is this?  If Intel, what's `uops_issued.any`?  (In uops / clock cycle).  3.7 IPC sounds like a lot, but less impressive if it's a lot of macro-fused cmp/jcc on a 6-wide Alder Lake.  Also, according to `perf list` on my Skylake, `tma_bad_speculation_group` includes `tma_machine_clears` as well as `tma_branch_mispredicts` - branches aren't the only thing CPUs speculate on.  `machine_clears.memory_ordering` can happen in multi-threaded code, and sometimes in single-threaded if a load sometimes reloads a recent store but sometimes doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's an i7-1165G7, so Tiger Lake. It's single-threaded CPU-bound code, so IPC would be quite high.

Comment: Also, `perf record -e branch-misses` should only be showing you branch instructions that had samples for branch mispredicts.  Not like the `cycles` event which is just time.  Maybe you don't have any branches with a high miss rate?   If you're seeing samples on instructions that aren't branches (or fused with branches), maybe try `perf record -e branch-misses:pp` or `:p` to make it precise (PEBS).  Or `perf stat -e br_misp_retired.all_branches_pebs` to use an Intel-specific event that exists on my CPU which forces PEBS.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think this is what I'm looking for! Just `-e branch-misses` was highlighting `add` and `mov` instructions, but with `:P` for maximum precision, it's now highlighting the time it's taking for jump instructions. Thanks very much. This gives me a path forward.

Answer (score 1):

`perf record -e branch-misses` should only be showing you branch instructions that had samples for branch mispredicts.  By default it doesn't use PEBS (Processor Event-Based Sampling) on Intel or IBS (Instruction-Based Sampling) on AMD so might have some skid aka skew effects, blaming a later instruction instead of the `jcc` or macro-fused `cmp/test/whatever/jcc` itself.

Use `event:pp` to ask for PEBS.  Or on Skylake, there's a `br_misp_retired.all_branches_pebs` alias.

```
perf record -e branch-misses:pp  ./a.out

perf report -Mintel        # on x86-64 to use Intel-syntax disassembly if you prefer
```

Related:

- https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/06/08/Advanced-profiling-topics-PEBS-and-LBR some of the CPU architecture behind skids in collecting a sample via an interrupt handler.
- https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html - the more `p`s, the more precise you're requesting it to be.  `:pp` requests 0 skid, `:ppp` *must* have 0 skid (failing if that's not possible).  `:p` is "must have constant skid".  On modern Intel, it would use PEBS which also gives 0 skid, same as `:pp`.

I don't know why it *doesn't* use PEBS by default when available; I thought it was about as efficient.  I've heard that PEBS buffers are usually very small, maybe only one sample, so you don't necessary get any gain in efficiency from fewer interrupts like you'd expect.

---

If that's still fairly evenly distributed, maybe you don't have any branches with a high miss rate.  0.66% overall miss rate is not very high, but if there are some problematic branches, they're worth looking at.  Depending on how many non-branch instructions there are between each branch, 0.66% overall branch miss rate could be a pretty decent number of uops per mispredict.

Looking at `uops_issued.any` vs. `uops_retired.retire_slots` will show you how many instructions from wrong paths of execution actually made it into the back-end, but the major cost of a mispredict is a delay in getting the correct path.

---

**Branches aren't the thing CPUs speculate on.**  In `perf` 6.5 on my machine, `perf list` shows that topdown bad-speculation (`tma_bad_speculation_group`) includes `tma_machine_clears` as well as `tma_branch_mispredicts`.

`machine_clears.memory_ordering` can easily happen in multi-threaded code, but is also possible in single-threaded if a load sometimes reloads a recent store but sometimes doesn't.  (CPUs dynamically predict whether a load needs to wait for addresses of previous stores to be known, or whether it can just assume no store forwarding and read from L1d cache.  https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/)

CPUs also speculate that loads / stores won't page-fault, but mis-speculation means a fault does happen so there isn't much useful it could be doing instead.  And the `page-faults` event exists so you can check on that.  Most other faults are fatal by default so they don't happen during normal operation.  So speculating that FP instructions don't trap is always correct speculation, for example.